# Cocoa Where to store a secret file to store Demo installation date

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa

Hello I am developing a simple protection for a Cocoa Mac Os X application for independent distribution. What would be the best place to store some secret hidden files on the user's disk to keep track of demo expiration ? also how to protect in case a user monitors the file system activity with tools such as FSEventer ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it as a generic password in the user's keychain.

[*Keychain Services Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897)

Comment: Thank you very much but in this case won't the informed user be able to edit the password at any time ?

Comment: Only if she recognizes what it is. Also, there's no reason to make it plain text. You can encode the timestamp in whatever obscure way you want before storing it as the password.

Comment: Thank you but I have noticed that then the App will need to ask the user for password to access the keychain... Would this cause problems ? thanks